# protractor StaleElementReferenceError: Element is no longer attached to the DOM

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

In my Angular app, when a user opens a page we initially load cached content and then follow it up with asynchronous calls to the server to poll the actual data and update the page.  I am trying to access element which is already displayed, but the pointer for the element has changed because page content was updated, even though nothing on that specific element has actually changed.

I tried different solutions, but still cant make it as stable as I want. I need something like try/catch blocks, because I do not want to to use browser.wait.

From the description looks like

```
browser.waitForAngular();
```

should handle $http calls, but it did not help.

Here is a code sample:

```
    element(by.id('closeEditTagsModal')).click();
    helper.waitElementToDisappear(element(by.css('body[class$="modal-open"]')));
    element(by.id('myBookingsTab')).click();
    helper.waitElementToDisappear(element(by.css('body[class$="loading"]')));
    try {
           (helper.waitElementToBeShown(element(by.repeater('b in currentbookings').row(0)).element(by.cssContainingText('.tagPill', 'TestTag')))).then(function() {
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('element was not found');
            throw err;
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        helper.waitElementToBeShown(element(by.repeater('b in currentbookings').row(0)).element(by.cssContainingText('.tagPill', 'TestTag')));
    }
```

Here is another sample where I tried to use try/catch, but looks like I did something wrong. I have this error in the try block:

> StaleElementReferenceError: Element is no longer attached to the DOM

The code for my help function:

```
var waitElementToBeShown = function (elm) {
browser.wait(function () {
    return elm.isPresent();
},10000);
browser.wait(function () {
    return elm.isDisplayed();
},10000);
};
```

I am trying to wait for the element to be available to be interacted with.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error is being thrown because the DOM changes between the two calls to `browser.wait`.  Instead of passing an elementPromise into `browser.wait`, you should pass in something more indirect.  You could pass the locator directly:

```
var waitElementToBeShown = function (elmLoc) {
  browser.wait(function () {
    return element(elmLoc).isPresent();
  },10000);
  browser.wait(function () {
    return element(elmLoc).isDisplayed();
  },10000);
}
```

But you don't always have a simple locator expression.  Maybe pass in a function that looks up the element?  That way the lookup will re-evaluate in each wait:

```
var waitElementToBeShown = function (elmFunc) {
  browser.wait(function () {
    return elmFunc().isPresent();
  },10000);
  browser.wait(function () {
    return elmFunc().isDisplayed();
  },10000);
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
waitElementToBeShown(function() {
  return element(by.repeater('b in currentbookings').row(0)).element(by.cssContainingText('.tagPill', 'TestTag')));
});
```

I'm not entirely confident in this answer, but it seems like it should work ...

Comment: I solved this kind of issues by asking developers to add flag which indicates that we have received success callback. I am not sure that it is the best way of doing such kind of things, but looks like it worked for me. I will also try your solution